# Expose Rest API as SOAP in WSO2 ESB

Tags: rest, soap, wsdl, soapui, wso2-esb

I have a Rest Api (Python/flask) that send response in json.
I need to **POST** a request with 3 parameters (body) using Soap, but I don't know about Soap and I don't understand the samples.
Can I just use a mediator to "translate" my Rest Api into a Soap Api ?
How can I test the **Post request with SoapUi** ? Do I need to use a wsdl file ?

I just need entry point documentation. 
  thanks.

Comment: There is this: http://www.soapui.org/getting-started/functional-testing.html

Comment: I'll do the tutorial asap and write back a comment.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You will need a WSDL to define your operation/web-service i.e SOAP Request incl 3 parameters. I use eclipse with the Web Tools plug in to create WSDLS. Then you'll need to get SOAP --> New Soap Project, and include the wsdl. LEt me know when you get there , and we can continue!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define your operations of the SOAP web service in a WSDL. Then you can create a new project in SOAPUI with this WSDL. Follow http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/operations-and-requests.html on how to create a request for a particular operation.

In ESB you can create an API for your REST service (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Creating+APIs). Now you need to use a payloadfactor mediator in your API in sequence to transform your SOAP(XML) request to JSON (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator). Then, this JSON request will be sent to the REST backend. If you again need to transfer the JSON response from the backend to SOAP, include another payload factory mediator to transform.